# Can't find element by class name or xpath selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to build a test, but I can't seem to find (and then click) on an element with a unique name that's in the page HTML.

It works up until here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.hallmark.nl/kaarten/verjaardag-man/")
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='https://www.hallmark.nl:443/kaarten/verjaardag-man/grappig-m/hallmark/een-jaguar-voor-je-verjaardag-3346861.aspx']"))).click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnShowSizepicker"))).click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Standaard']"))).click()
```

I'm trying to click the button 'Binnenkant ' (note the trailing space).
For this, I've tried:

`elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('primaryButton').click()`

`elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[.="Binnenkant "]').click()`

`elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//*[@id="CardSelectBar"]/div[3]/button[2]/text()).click() #xpath copied from Chrome`

But I get a 'no such element' error each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 classes on this particular page: showDesktop and hideDesktop. Both include the button you search for. Try this Xpath:

```
"//div[contains(@class, 'showDesktop')]//button[contains(text(),'Binnenkant')]"
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! I guess a 'duplicate name' error would be helpful for debugging.